# Android Studio 4.1.1 not responded to keyboard input in windows 10

Tags: android, android-studio-4.1

I am using Android Studio 4.1.1 in windows10 laptop having AMD processor.
Some time the Android Studio editor not responded to keyboard input. Hence I can't enter/edit the XML or Java text in the java and xml files. I have tried  Invalidate caches and restart option under the File menu. But the problem has not been solved.  How can I overcome this fault. Please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reverting Android Studio IDE settings to its default the problem faced has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

Was same problem. Solved after deactivating "Tools - Vim emulator" (IdeaVim plugin)